# Multiple Necessary and Sufficient Conditions

Tags: logic

Does `if and only if` allow for multiple necessary and sufficient conditions?

In other words, can there be multiple hypotheses that are both necessary and sufficient for a conclusion? Any examples would be great.

Also, can you provide any intuition as to why $(p \leftrightarrow q) \wedge (p \leftrightarrow r)$ is not logically equivalent to $p \leftrightarrow (q \wedge r)$?

Comment: For $p,q,r$ having values $F,T,F$ respectively, $p ↔ ( q \land r)$ is $T$ while $(p ↔ q) \land (p ↔ r)$ is $F$.

Answer (score 1):

Your $p\leftrightarrow (q\land r)$ is an example of multiple necessary and sufficient conditions for $p$.

Using a truth table, you can confirm that the following is not always true:

$$(((p\leftrightarrow q) \land  (p\leftrightarrow r))\leftrightarrow(p\leftrightarrow(q\land r)))$$

It is false only when $p$ is false and only one of $q$ and $r$ is true.

(Nice truth table generator at http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs103/tools/truth-table-tool/ A clean, slick interface.)

Answer (score 1):

> Also, can you provide any intuition as to why $p \leftrightarrow q \wedge p \leftrightarrow r$ is not logically equivalent to $p \leftrightarrow (q \wedge r)$?

It is because, if (and only if) two predicates are equivalent, then also their negations are equivalent.

$$\begin{align}A\leftrightarrow B \quad\equiv&\quad \neg A\leftrightarrow \neg B
\\ p \leftrightarrow q~\wedge ~p\leftrightarrow r  \quad\equiv&\quad \neg p\leftrightarrow\neg q~\wedge~\neg p\leftrightarrow \neg r
\\ p~\leftrightarrow~(q\wedge r) \quad\equiv&\quad \neg p~\leftrightarrow(\neg q\vee \neg r)
\end{align}$$

In the first case, $p\leftrightarrow q~\wedge~ p\leftrightarrow r$, then if $p$ is false so too are *both* $q$ *and* $r$ (ie: neither may be true).

In the second case, $p ~\leftrightarrow~ (q \wedge r)$, then if $p$ is false so too is *either* $q$ *or* $r$ (ie: at most one may be true). [vis: de Morgan's Laws]

---

$$\begin{align}(p\leftrightarrow q)~\wedge~(p\leftrightarrow r) \quad\equiv&\quad (p\to q)~\wedge~ (p\to r)~\wedge~\color{silver}{(}(q\to p)~\wedge~(r\to p)\color{silver}{)}\\p~\leftrightarrow~(q\wedge r) \quad\equiv&\quad (p\to q)~\wedge~ (p\to r)~\wedge~((q\to p)~\vee~(r\to p))\end{align}$$